# Uploading a new APK to production. For new version of an Android app.

Tags: android, google-play

*This is not a duplicate because the other similar questions are very incomplete. So I am asking for the gaps in information.*

---

I just added an update to my app. I followed examples on this site that said to update the code like this adding the **versionCode** and **versionName**. The instructions said to increment the code by 1, and the version to whatever I want it called. So I have this.

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="juangallardo.emofortunecookie"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1.0">
```

Then I hit **Build --> Clean**. Then build --> **Generate Signed APK**

[image]

then chose release

[image]

Then I uploaded what was generated. I did check to make sure that the file was just recently modified to ensure that I was not uploading a previous file. But I got this error.

[image]

Comment: In your build.gradle file, check if you have defined "android ->  defaultConfig -> versionCode 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to specify the version information in the manifest manually for an Android Studio project and you instead have to modify the Gradle build file.

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="juangallardo.emofortunecookie">
```

#### app/build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "juangallardo.emofortunecookie"
    [..]
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1.0"
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I wonder why the Android documentation fails to mention this.

Comment: Android tutorials and documentation are split between Android Studio and Eclipse. Newer pieces favor Android Studio but older ones have not yet been updated. As you might guess knowing that, when using Eclipse, the manifest file must be modified directly.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're using Android Studio. You'll have to edit your `build.gradle` which may be overiding your manifest settings.

```
android {
    ...

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1.0"
         ...
    }
```